# Do I have to explicitly remove all data retrieval listeners (value, child) when the user is signed out from Firebase?

Tags: firebase, firebase-realtime-database, firebase-authentication

Do I have to explicitly remove all data retrieval listeners (value, child) when the user is signed out from Firebase? Or is this done automatically when signOut is called?

Comment: it needs to be done explicitly since you can read data without auth if the rules are public

Answer (score 0):

Yes, you must remove those listeners explicitly.

`signOut()` only signs out the user, and does NOT remove the database listener. [The documentation](https://firebase.google.com/docs/reference/js/firebase.auth.Auth#signOut) says:

> **signOut**
>
> `signOut()` returns [`firebase.Promise`](https://firebase.google.com/docs/reference/js/firebase.Promise.html) containing void
>
> Signs out the current user.
>
> **Returns**
>
> non-null [firebase.Promise](https://firebase.google.com/docs/reference/js/firebase.Promise.html) containing void

Firebase Authentication and Firebase Realtime Database are separate. You can even use one without the another.

Answer (score 0):

When you sign out the user, any listener on a location that requires authentication will be cancelled automatically and its [cancel callback](https://firebase.google.com/docs/reference/js/firebase.database.Query#on) will be invoked.

Listeners at locations that don't require authentication will continue to function.